# Vim + latex-suite - modify output file name

Tags: vim, latex, pdflatex

I want to create a custom compile rule that takes foo.tex and outputs foo_bar.pdf

I have used the following configurations in my texrc, but I have not found a way to exclude the .tex extension from the output name.

`TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_bar = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style -halt-on-error -jobname=%_bar $*'`

Result: foo.tex_bar.pdf

`TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_bar = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style -halt-on-error -jobname=$*_bar $*'`

Result: foo.tex_bar.pdf

`TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_bar = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style -halt-on-error -jobname=bar_$ $*'`

Result: bar_$.tex

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! I realize my ignorance is showing, but I'd like to understand where that syntax comes from? Is it part of RegExp?

Comment: Posted as an answer, with more details and a reference to the docs for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:r` filename modifier after `%` to remove its extension, before adding the new suffix. Filename modifiers usually work in contexts where `%` is supported (such as using `:!` to run an external shell command.)

In your case, `-jobname=%:r_bar` should do the job.

See [`:help filename-modifiers`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers) for the full list of modifiers and how they work.